# What's the easiest way to add a comment for a particular Revision in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to be able to comment on a particular Revision in SVN (using TortoiseSVN). The only way I can see to add a comment (like Release Version X.y)  that would be visible in the Revision Graph of *all* files is with a Tag but that seems like more of a way to Branch the code (and that's not why I want to label it).

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Log messages are comments on a particular revision, usually entered at the time that revision is committed. I assume you know that, though. So what are you trying to do that can't be done with a log message?

Comment: IIRC, the Log message only shows up for the files that were altered in the Revision. So if I happen to look at the REvision History for a folder that wasn't updated in  the Rev# that has the log message, I wouldn't see the message, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are intended for exactly what you've described. The difference between a Tag and a Branch is that the Tag should remain stationary, like a bookmark of sorts, whereas you create a Branch with the intention of committing to it.

In svn, there is no implementation difference between branches and tags -- you distinguish between them by naming them "branches" and "tags".

To mark a release, you tag it. In fact, I usually say the phrase "tag a release". :)

Comment: And further you can branch a tag if you choose later in time.  You can also tag a revision in the past (not just the latest).